# re-order numpy matrix to line up with ids in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df which has a column called id where each value is unique.

```
  df

  id    name
  A     abc
  B     bcv
  C     dsf
  D     ere
  E     pmn
```

I pass this unique set of ids to a function. The function returns two things, one a dataframe, df_matrix which also contains a column called id. The second thing it returns is a covaraince matrix (array of float64).

```
 df_matrix

 id    name
  C     dsf
  A     abc
  E     pmn
  B     bcv
```

Every id in df_matrix will be in df but the opposite is not true. So in the example above df has an id "D" which is not in df_matrix. Also you will notice the order is different

```
 covariance matrix

     C   A   E   B
  C  1   2   3   4
  A  2   5   7   8
  E  3   7   9   10
  B  4   8   10  11
```

What I need to do is re-order the covariance matrix so the id's line up with my dataframe df & also to take account of any missing ids.

the output I'm looking for is,

```
    A   B   C   D    E
 A  5   8   2   NaN  7
 B  8   11  4   NaN  10
 C  2   4   1   NaN  3
 D  NaN NaN NaN NaN  Nan
 E  7   10  3   NaN  9
```

I tried merging the matrix with the dataframe, whilst this lines the matrix rows with the dataframe it doesn't adjust the columns of the matrix. I'm not sure the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `reindex`:

```
cov_mat.reindex(df['id']).reindex(df['id'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
id    A     B    C   D     E
id                          
A   5.0   8.0  2.0 NaN   7.0
B   8.0  11.0  4.0 NaN  10.0
C   2.0   4.0  1.0 NaN   3.0
D   NaN   NaN  NaN NaN   NaN
E   7.0  10.0  3.0 NaN   9.0
```

---

**Update** You can also set `id` as index for `df2` then reindex as `df1['id']` before calculation of covariance matrix.